# Run the while-loop again with the same variable and start the script again without closing it?

Tags: python, loops, variables

```
import random

x = random.randint(0,20)
y = int(input("guess the number from 0 to 20: \n"))

while True:
    if y == x:
        print("well done")
        print(x)
        stoper=input()
        break
    elif y < x:
        print("too low")
        stoper=input()
        break
    elif y > x:
        print("too high")
        stoper=input()
        break
    else:
        stoper=input()
        break
```

That is the code.This script takes a random number from 0 to 20 and has the user guess it.In case the guess is larger/smaller than the number,the program prints the info and the number. How do I guess the number again without changing the number `x`?

In case anyone's wondering the `stoper` input variable is just so the scripr doesn't instantly close after running the code. As for the running it again without closing it, the question refers to the script going again with the new `x` and new guesses without closing the script.

Comment: Put the line with the `input` into the `while` loop and `break` only when `x==y`.

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint
x = randint(0,20)
y = int(input("guess the number from 0 to 20: \n"))

while True:
  if y == x:
      for i in range(100): #mimics resetting the screen
          print("")
      print("well done. Try again!")
  elif y < x:
      print("too low")
  elif y > x:
      print("too high")
  y = int(input("guess the number from 0 to 20: \n"))
```